# Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[employeService -> Http]:

Tags: angular

I am facing above mentioned error when I am using `Http` inside the constructor of my service.

Employee service  code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class employeService {
    constructor(public http: Http){ }

    getEmployeename(): Observable<string> {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:53656/api/values/Getdata').map((resp: Response) =>
            resp.json()
        );
    }
}
```

I am calling the service directly (not from `app.module.ts` file) inside employee component as

Employee Component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { employeService } from './Service/service';

@Component({  
    templateUrl: './app.employee.html',
    providers: [employeService]
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
    empName: string;

    constructor(private empService: employeService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.empService.getEmployeename().subscribe(empName =>
            this.empName = empName
        );
    }
}
```

And I have this error message in Console :

```
core.js:1598 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:       
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[employeService -> Http]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[employeService -> Http]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[employeService -> Http]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[employeService -> Http]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
at
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to import HTTPModule into your main module.

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ],
  imports: [
    ......
    HttpModule
  ]
....
```

## Update

As per latest versions you should use `HttpClientModule` instead of `HttpModule`

Import like this

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ],
  imports: [
    ......
    HttpClientModule
  ]
....
```

Comment: Thanks! Working fine now. I was not using above shown in app.module because I was expecting to use the service only in employee component.

Comment: But everything you need to use in your application need to be injected in module

Comment: Note: This answer is *outdated* ! You should instead use `HttpClientModule` as per Angular's official documentation.

Comment: @MilanVelebit Thanks for Update, I have Updated the answer as well

Comment: I was working with an upgraded project and HttpClientModule wasn't fixing this, but the deprecated HttpModule was. Once I discovered that I can now start looking at why my code is not working with the new HttpClientModule.

Answer (score 0):

in app.module.ts
you should use HttpClientModule
alsoimport your service provider into provider