# Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'

Tags: node.js, angularjs

If i run this code, i get an error,  Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

```
  public exportExcel(jsonData: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    //Excel Title, Header, Data
    const header: string[] =  Object.keys(jsonData[0]);
    const data = jsonData;

    //Create workbook and worksheet
    let workbook = new Workbook();
    let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(excelFileName);

    //Add Header Row
    let headerRow = worksheet.addRow(header);

    // Cell Style : Fill and Border
    headerRow.eachCell((cell, number) => {
      cell.fill = {
        type: 'pattern',
        pattern: 'solid',
        fgColor: { argb: 'FFFFFF00' },
        bgColor: { argb: 'FF0000FF' }
      }
      cell.border = { top: { style: 'thin' }, left: { style: 'thin' }, bottom: { style: 'thin' }, right: { style: 'thin' } }
    })
    // Add Data and Conditional Formatting
    data.forEach((element) => {
      let eachRow = [];
      header.forEach((headers) => {
        eachRow.push(element[headers])
      })
      if (element.isDeleted === "Y") {
        let deletedRow = worksheet.addRow(eachRow);
        deletedRow.eachCell((cell, number) => {
          cell.font = { name: 'Calibri', family: 4, size: 11, bold: false, strike: true };
        })
      } else {
        worksheet.addRow(eachRow);
      }
    })
```

...

ERROR in node_modules/exceljs/index.d.ts(1648,34): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

Comment: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/971 can help

Comment: ok thank you i will try

Comment: @dev but i get this information, what it´s mean?  
100 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 429 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 9.43 MB [initial] [rendered]
Time: 6775ms

Comment: Not sure about those lines. but did you tried the suggestions mentioined in the above link and did it helped?

Comment: Yes i tried and get in the Chrome console this errors: core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[EventOverviewPageComponent -> ExportService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[EventOverviewPageComponent -> ExportService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ExportService!

Comment: Please check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776562/uncaught-in-promise-error-staticinjectorerrorappmoduleoptions  || https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718852/uncaught-in-promise-error-staticinjectorerrorappmoduleemployeservice-h

Comment: @dev THANK YOU VERY MUCH; THANKS;THANKS;THANKS

Comment: update @types/node with `npm i -D @types/node@14.17.6`

Answer (score 22):

#### Solution targetting Angular8+ Projects:

This is a known [bug](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/1150), caused due to the *incompatibility* of `exceljs` with the version of `@types/node`. I faced similar issue with Angular 10.

2 possible solutions exists:

1. **Recommended**: Update your `tsconfig.app.json` file with `"types": ["node"]`

[image]

2. If you are okay *without having type support*, then you can simply use the below import:
   `import * as Excel from "exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js";`

Comment: In my case this worked only if applied to tsconfig.app.json in the project root.

Answer (score 2):

Just Open index.d.ts file from yours exceljs node_modules

[image]

and replace this line 
**dictionary: Buffer | NodeJS.TypedArray | DataView | ArrayBuffer; // deflate/inflate only, empty dictionary by default**

with this

**dictionary: Buffer  | DataView | ArrayBuffer; // deflate/inflate only, empty dictionary by default**

and then just ng serve

Comment: LOL!  What about the next time they install their dependencies???  Would you expect them to change the code in their node modules every time?

Comment: you can use package-patch if you HAVE to go with this approach